# AWS EC2 - How to create a wildcard to receive any domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am building a virtual store platform. My platform is multiple store.

I need to create a wildcard so that my ec2 can receive request from any domain.

That is... The user points his domain to the IP of the EC2 and the request arrives directly at the nginx of ec2. No need to get configuring domain on route 53.

I need it to be automatic. The only work is the client that will point the domain to the ip of ec2.

Does anyone know how this can be done? If I point the domain to the ip of ec2 will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing and accepting all domains in Nginx, you could do a "catch-all", for this you need to setup `server_name _`

From: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

> In catch-all server examples the strange name “_” can be seen:

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    ...
}
```

As a reference: 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names

Comment: Thanks for answering! But my question is regarding the configuration of aws. I pointed my domain to the ip of ec2. did not work, but I do not know if it's because of propagation or some error

Comment: normally the IP's from the instances are private so you will need to either use an elastic IP and point the domain to the public IP,  also check your security groups /rules to allow traffic to port 80/443